# Deploying Office 2013 Addins on Win Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, office-2013, office-addins

I have an Excel 2013 Add-in.

I can't figure out why it won't load through Remote Desktop gateway if the user haven't first logged in through a normal RDP connection.

When looking into the registry on the server it seems office is missing some entries that used to be there such as:
CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\

I only got 
CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\

Comment: What is the add-in? Are you running office on the server?

Comment: Sorry the Add-in is a Excel xlam. Excel 2013 is installed on the server, when loggin in through RDP everything works fine. The Add-in installs and loads first time user opens Excel. But when the user only logs in through the gateway with out going into RDP first, the add-in is not loaded.